# Browser Link In Visual Studio Is Not Working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I'm trying to launch my web application (asp.net MVC) with debugging mode using **Browser Link** To Enable Edit Operations during Browser

but actually when i try to do this (Browser Link Not Working and it ask me to register the page inspector in the Web.Config)

[image]

---

**Edit**

and when i add the following to web.config nothing Happens

```
<add key="VisualStudioDesignTime:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Enabled"/>
```

still i can't see that any browser connect through **Browser Link**

with knowledge that I Have Enabled `debug=true` in web.config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6" />
```

and knowing that i have uninstall web essentials Package

[image]

Comment: were you able to get this working. Facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://itq.nl/short-visual-studio-2013-browser-link-tip/) post very useful.

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
         type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
               Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Take care in that the `<modules>` element might already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="VisualStudioDesignTime:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Enabled"/>
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: thanks, i tried to do this but nothing shows that the browser connect to the Browser Link, please see the updated Post

Comment: Does your project run under .Net 4 or later?

Comment: My Application Running Under .Net 4.6